# Find and replace in a Ruby multi dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there an elegant way to find and replace any integers superior to 3 (as example) in a multidimensional array? The array may have the dimension 1, 2, 3, or more. Just an example of a such array:

```
[ [ [ 3, 3, 5 ], 
    [ 4, 3, 3 ] ], 
  [ [ 3, 2, 3 ], 
    [ 0, 3, 8 ] ] ]
```

I would like to do so without flatten the array.

Comment: With the number 3 (because it's the maximum needed value in the example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following sepp2k idea, here is a possible implementation:

```
class Object
  def deep_map(&block)
    if self.respond_to? :each
      result = []
      self.each do |e|
        result << e.deep_map(&block)
      end
      return result
    else
      return block.call(self)
    end
  end  
end
```

Then apply deep_map as you wish on the array:

```
> [[[3, 3, 5], [4, 3, 3]], [[3, 2, 3], [0, 3, 8]]].deep_map { |e| e > 3 ? 0 : e }
=> [[[3, 3, 0], [0, 3, 3]], [[3, 2, 3], [0, 3, 0]]]
```

Or, more briefly:

```
class Object
  def deep_map(&block)
    respond_to?(:map) ? map{|e| e.deep_map(&block)} : block.call(self)
  end
end
```

Or, polymorphically:

```
class Object
  def deep_map(&block); block.call(self) end
end

class Array
  def deep_map(&block); map{|e| e.deep_map(&block)} end
end
```

Comment: @i-blis, I've added a shorter version of what you wrote, if you want it.

Comment: `each` after `map` in the shorter version should be removed.

Comment: You can also do it polymorphically, as I added.

Comment: Thanks sawa. The shorter version is even more readable. The polymorphic solution is pretty elegant. I do not see this often in Ruby code – is this a popular coding idiom?

Comment: I would say no, the polymorphic solution isn't a common idiom in Ruby. In Ruby, it's more common to use duck-typing. In other words, an object may respond to `map` but not be an `Array`, in which case the "brief" version would work but the polymorphic one wouldn't.

Comment: @i-blis, @Jonathan Rails code does pretty much of polymorphic coding, and using polymorphism is one important point of adopting object orientation. It reduces conditional statements. @Jonathan's point is not a criticism against using polymorphism. It is just that my choice of `Array` assumed limited usage. I can define it on the `Enumerable` module, and Jonathan's issue will disappear, but I don't think a non-array would be used for creating a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a `deep_map` method, which calls `map` on the array and then for each element test whether it's a sub-array. If it is, call `deep_map` recursively with the sub-array, otherwise yield the element.

You can then use that `deep_map` method to transform the inner elements of your multi-dimensional array without affecting its structure.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I've done this right, `f(x)` will traverse a multidimensional Array until it finds one containing something that isn't an *Array* or subclass of *Array*, at which point it will yield the innermost *Array* to the block and replace it with the block's return value.

```
def f x, &block
  x.map do |a|
    if a.first.class.ancestors.include? Array
      f a, &block
    else
      yield a
    end
  end
end

p(f [ [ [ 3, 3, 5 ],
        [ 4, 3, 3 ] ],
      [ [ 3, 2, 3 ],
        [ 0, 3, 8 ] ] ] do |e|
    e.reject { |x| x > 3 }
  end
)
```

Comment: Thank you, @DigitalRoss. Your code is very clean. But, because my question wasn't very clear, I would like to keep the array structure. Anyway, thanks again!